# Android: Adapting app to small screens with layouts including other layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, screen-size

I finished my app with all my xml layouts in the "layout" folder, which is used by normal-sized screens. So now I am starting with small screens and create a folder called "layout-small" right under the "layout" folder in "res".

I did some modifications in the smaller layout with smaller buttons and margins and then tried to running it on a normal screen and a small screen to see if each screen would use the layout it should, but both use the normal layout. The small screen doesn't use the small layout.

I believe this is due to the fact that the Java class that uses the setContent() method uses a layout which in turn includes another layout which also includes a third layout.

Here is my code for more clarity. The 3 activity_main.xml app_bar_main.xml and content_main.xml layout files are in res/layout and res/layout-small as well, with differences in button sizes only in content_main.xml.

**Home.java :**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

/**fields*/
private Button butVentes, butLocations, butRecherche, butFavoris, butContact, butSocial;   //Buttons for home screen
private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private NavigationView navigationView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /**toolbar*/
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    /**drawer*/
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    /**navigationView*/
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

/*...*/

}
```

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**app_bar_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivities.Home">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

**content_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_background_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/app_accueil_background"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivities.Home"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonVentes"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_view_list"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/content_main_vente"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLocations"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_view_list"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/content_main_location"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRecherche"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/content_main_recherche"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonFavoris"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_star_accueil"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/content_main_favoris"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonContact"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_contacts"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/content_main_contact"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSocial"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/content_main_social"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If it is just to change dimens use the dimen.xml file, if you need to change the layout for tablet for example prefer sw600dp and sw820dp to things like  large, xlarge those will be deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of creating other layout folders, just maintain different dimension folders like :
 values-sw320dp - 1dp
 values-sw360dp - 1.12dp
 values-sw410dp - 1.28dp
 values-sw480dp - 1.5dp

Comment: So I keep all my xml layout files in the "res/layout" folder and create new dimension values files where I change the values? But like the names of the dimensions should remain the same right? and android selects the best value depending on the screen size?

Comment: yes,names of dimensions across all files should be same and android selects the value depends on screen size.  BTW, 1dp,1.12dp etc.. ratios for corresponding folders..

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll give it a try and accept your answer if it works